# How to get data out of "then" in node js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node js. I want to ask how to get data out of ".then" after the query from database?

Refer to [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfKx6.png)

When I do `console.log(theResult)`; it is returning as undefined.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i'm trying to understand it, do you have simple answer ?

Comment: No, I don't have a simple answer. It's not a simple question, as it requires understanding what async code is. There are several comprehensive answers that describe the nature of asynchronous code and how to handle it in the linked question.

Comment: ohh okay, thank you for the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the power of **async/await** in that case and return the value from the function and use it anywhere.

Here your code goes for query which you have to wrap in async function and return the value:

```
const getValue = async () => {
    return query.yourQueryMethod(conditions)
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
}
```

Here the code where you execute your main async function:

```
const executeQueryAndExtractData = async () => {
    var myData = await getValue();
    console.log ({ myData });
}

// Here you execute the async function
executeQueryAndExtractData();
```